# Why does ISO C forbid casting nonscalar to the same type

Tags: c, language-lawyer

```
struct Foo {
    int dummy;
} bar;

int main(void)
{
    /* This statement causes GCC to produce the warning:
     * ISO C forbids casting nonscalar to the same type */
    (volatile struct Foo)bar;

    /* The warning may be silenced like so.
     * Is this form superior or just trickier? Why? */
    *(volatile struct Foo *)&bar;

    return 0;
}
```

What evil is the compiler/standard trying to guard against?

Backstory:
The real code in question is using a circular buffer/queue shared between ISRs and the background. The background code continually polls the queue. I was looking to avoid pessimizing access to the queue while preventing the compiler from optimizing the polling of the queue such that the code hops into a tight `label: goto label;` loop when the queue is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning message is a bit misleading. ISO C doesn't just forbid
casting a nonscalar to the same type; it forbids casting a nonscalar
to or from *any* type. Both the operand of a cast operator, and the
type specified in the cast itself, must be of scalar type (either
arithmetic or pointer).

There's an exception to this, but it doesn't apply here. If the
target type is void, the operand can be of any type.

Comment: More info: historically some compilers allowed `(T)x` with the meaning `*(T *)&x` , I don't recall whether gcc was one of those

Comment: For completeness sake I located the relevant portion of the rationale...
Rationale for International Standard—Programming Languages—C V5.10
Section 6.7.3 Page 77 Lines 7-10

A cast of a value to a qualified type has no effect; the qualification (volatile, say) can have no effect on the access since it has occurred prior to the cast. If it is necessary to access a non-volatile object using volatile semantics, the technique is to cast the address of the object to the appropriate pointer-to-qualified type, then dereference that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

the posted struct foo definition also is declaring an instance of the struct, named 'bar'.

Then inside the code a second instance of the struct is being declared, again with a name of 'bar'.

the second 'bar' is shadowing the first instance.

that, alone, will cause the compiler to raise a warning.

here is the correct usage (still has the shadowing problem)

```
struct Foo {
    int dummy;
} bar;

int main(void)
{
    /* This statement causes GCC to produce the warning:
     * ISO C forbids casting nonscalar to the same type */
    volatile struct Foo bar;

    /* The warning may be silenced like so.
     * Is this form superior or just trickier? Why? */
    //*(volatile struct Foo *)&bar;

    return 0;
}
```

Notice, not trying to redefine struct Foo as volatile, rather declaring the local variable 'bar' as being volatile

Comment: even the corrected usage example will raise a warning about the unused variable 'bar' in the main function